# Need Help Getting Comment Count for Every Drupal 8 User Account

Tags: mysql, drupal-8

Im trying to write a MySQL query that will count the comments of every user in my Drupal 8 database.  I need to do this in MySQL for a report.

I tried looking at the tables in mysql and I can't figure out how to link comments to users.  I don't see a junction table and/or foreign keys that link the 2 tables. Users / Comment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show the table structures `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for relevant tables.

Comment: Looking at https://www.drupal.org/files/Drupal8_UPsitesWeb_Schema_10-19-2013.png and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!comment!src!Entity!Comment.php/function/Comment%3A%3AgetOwner/8.2.x I am guessing it might have to do with entity_id on the comments, but not sure if entities can be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 8 the table comment_field_data contains the cid (Comment Id) and the uid (Author's User Id).

```
SELECT count(cid), uid FROM comment_field_data GROUP BY uid;
```

Including nice column headers and adding the user's name:

```
SELECT COUNT(cid) AS 'Total # of Comments', comment_field_data.uid AS 'User Id', users_field_data.name as 'Username'
FROM comment_field_data
LEFT JOIN users_field_data ON comment_field_data.uid = users_field_data.uid
GROUP BY comment_field_data.uid;
```